# Clean up intersecting geometry

Tags: topology

iam repairing a model that has intersecting geometry. It is a really dense mesh that was conected via boolean. So it is firmly connected but in a wrong way and i have no way to erase this zero thick wall without selecting it manualy, which is in that dense mesh almost impossible. Is there a way to isolate this kind of geometry and delete it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the mesh is watertight but has areas with zero thickness then these areas are non-manifold. In Blender 2.80 you can select them using *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold*.

[image]

For 2.79 and earlier take a look at [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) by [gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3).

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to select the outline of it selecting edges or vertices with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click to select the shortest path between them and then use Select Loop Inner Region function:

[image]

Comment: I think that these advices are good I didnt know about selection of non manifold geometry, its pitty that it select only the edge, not the whole polygons. The selection came to my mind as well, but the geometry was really messy and big. I ended up completely deleting the whole perimetr of intersecting geometry and remodeling it.

Comment: I noticed that usually this kind of work is not very pleasant and it seems like it takes a whole lot of time because it takes effort, however in reality, if you actually measure the time you spend on it, even though unpleasant this is a surprisingly fast process.

Comment: Yeah, probably because its boring :D